# How to Convert Pandas any Function with mean into SQL (Snowflake)?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem**

I'm converting a Python Pandas data pipeline into a series of views in Snowflake. The transformations are mostly straightforward, but some of them seem to be more difficult in SQL. I'm wondering if there are straightforward methods.

**Question**

How can I write a Pandas `df['col'].any()` as simply as possible using SnowSQL? I'm assuming a group by with some aggregate function, but `ANY` isn't implemented in SnowSQL.

**Example**

Here's a sample dataframe with the result I'm looking for:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0, 0, 1, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan]})
>>> any_value = (df['col'] == 3).any()
>>> any_value
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowpark [any_value](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.any_value.html):

> snowflake.snowpark.functions.any_value(e: ColumnOrName) → Column[source]
>
> Returns a non-deterministic any value for the specified column. This is an aggregate and window function.

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import numpy as np
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import any_value

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.create_dataframe([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, np.nan, np.nan],\
                                  schema = ["col"])
    return df.agg(any_value("col"))
```

---

EDIT:

If the goal is to check existence of value in the dataframe it could be done with [filter](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.create_dataframe([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, np.nan, np.nan],\
                                  schema = ["col"])
    any_val = not not df.filter("col=3").collect()
    return any_val
```

Output:

```
any_val = not not df.filter("col=3").collect()
# True

any_val = not not df.filter("col=2").collect()
# False
```

Comment: Not the functionality I'm looking for--this chooses any value from a data frame. I want to evaluate a boolean condition across an entire column

Comment: @whoopscheckmate Then you could use filter and check if it returns not empty array

Comment: I agree with the edit. I think that the `any` pandas function and `any_value` Snowflake function are very different. So that first part really doesn't make sense for this question. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @whoopscheckmate 'any_value' could also make sense. For instance if the goal is to return actual value(instead of only checking for existence) "df.filter(cond).agg(any_value(...))"

Comment: Sure, but the `any` pandas function (the one I'm trying to convert), just doesn't do that: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html. It's not my goal in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_contaisn https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains

```
where array_contains(3::variant, col)
```